# How to efficiently initialize texture with zeroes?

Tags: opengl

I need to initialize an OpenGL 2D texture with zeroes.

Why? I render to this texture with OpenCL. Roughly, rendering stages are:

1. Create RGBA texture, initialize with zeros (so it contains transparent black pixels)
2. OpenCL: compute color of pixels where some objects are visible and write them to this texture
3. OpenGL: add environment mapping to the transparent pixels and display final image

I therefore do not need to pass any actual texture data to `glTexImage2d`. But according to the spec, when I pass data=NULL, the texture memory is allocated but not initialized.

Allocating a client-side memory filled with zeroes and passing to `glTexImage2D` is not a very good option although only one I can think of.

EDIT: I actually want to init only alpha component (RGB will get overriden anyway), but I doubt this make the situation any easier.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1: Given a width and a height for a texture:

```
std::vector<GLubyte> emptyData(width * height * 4, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &emptyData[0]);
```

For maximum efficiency, you should leave some time between when you call this and when OpenCL starts its work.

2: Attach it to an FBO and use [glClearBuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glClearBuffer).

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture, 0); //Only need to do this once.
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0); //Only need to do this once.
GLuint clearColor[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
glClearBufferuiv(GL_COLOR, 0, clearColor);
```

This seems like it should be faster, since there is no CPU-GPU DMA going on. But the binding and unbinding of FBOs may introduce inefficiencies. Then again, it may not. Profile it to make sure.

Note that this only works for image formats that can be used as render targets. So not compressed textures.

3: Given sufficient drivers, you can use the new [ARB_clear_texture](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/clear_texture.txt) extension:

```
glClearTexImage(texture, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &clearColor);
```

Note that this only works for image formats whose data can be provided by [standard pixel transfers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer). So not compressed formats.

Comment: Never heard about `glClearBuffer`. Is this from a very new version? Does it have any advantages over `glClear` (or is the latter even deprecated)?.

Comment: @Christian: The main advantage of ClearBuffer is that you can clear specific buffers. If you have multiple buffers in the framebuffer, multiple render targets, then you may want to clear different ones to different colors. Or not clear some at all. You can't do that with `glClear`; it clears all the buffers to the same clear color. `glClear` isn't deprecated, and `glClearBuffer` comes from GL 3.0 (there's no extension for it).

Comment: Note that glClearTexImage only works if the texture storage has been previously allocated, using either a call to glTexImage* or glTexStorage*.  Simply creating the texture using glBindTexture is not enough.  But this also applies to glTexSubImage2D, of course.

Comment: Also, glClearTexImage only works for non-compressed formats. But I have a question. I can see that the ARB function is mapped (non-zero) and that the defines are 1. However, even though the texture storage should be created (handle is non-zero) using the glTexImage/glTexStorage/glTexCopy functions, I still get GL errors sayin the texture does not exist. Any ideas's?

Comment: @StarShine: Thanks for the reminder about compressed texture clearing. As for your question, that's what the "ask question" button is for.

Comment: Never mind, the error I made was to supply the target spec instead of the texture handle. It works on my 4.3. Will have to test on 3.3 later.

Comment: Method 1 is way too slow by reading data from CPU to GPU. Method 2 glClearBuffer may use the same mechanism of rendering as  @neodelphi suggested, where the texture is the target and be rendered.

Comment: @user1914692: "*Method 2 glClearBuffer may use the same mechanism of rendering as neodelphi suggested*" So might Method 3, just with a color the user provides. Assuming that everything will be implemented in the worst possible way accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @NicolBolas glClearTexImage takes the texture handle, not the texture target. There is no need to bind the texture, the requirement is only to be initialized and non-compressed format. Could you please edit your answer  to correct it?

Answer (score 7):

Just a heads up: The new [GL_ARB_clear_texture](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/clear_texture.txt) (core in 4.4) extension specifically addresses this problem.

Comment: This is true, but a word of warning: You definitely want to profile this. On my system, glClearTexture is MUCH slower than using a framebuffer and glClear / glClearBuffer.

Comment: @Jagoly did you properly profile using GPU timer queries?

Comment: No, just using the frametime. It's not just a little bit slower, though; clearTexture (two calls, rgb8 + 24bit depth) took more than three times longer than clear. I already had the framebuffer set up. The difference was even greater for depth only (5x).

Answer (score 4):

1. `glTexSubImage` is filled with the whole image:

   ```cpp
   GLfloat* pData = new GLfloat[1024*768*4];
   memset(pData, 0x00, 1024*768*4*sizeof(GLfloat));
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_ImageTex);
   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1024, 768, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pData);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
   delete pData;
   ```
2. use **Pixel Buffer** to copy data from gpu, this method is faster and better

   i. init PBO

   ```cpp
   glGenBuffers(1, &m_PixelBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, m_PixelBuffer);
   glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT*4*sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   GLfloat* pData = nullptr;
   pData = (GLfloat*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
   memset(pData, 0x00, 1024*768*4*sizeof(GLfloat));
   glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);
   ```

   ii.

   ```cpp
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, m_PixelBuffer);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_ImageTex);
   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set the texture as the rendering target for the first pass and draw a black primitive. It may be faster since there are no memory transfert between the ram and graphic card.

Comment: Good point. But can I manage to set alpha=0 with this approach? I actually want to init just alpha, I don't bother with RGB components.

Comment: Using glClearColor and glClear may be better. glClearColor accepts alpha.