# Clearing DRAW framebuffer only works if attached to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0?

Tags: opengl, textures, framebuffer

I am trying to initialize a texture with all zeros, using DRAW framebuffer as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195130/how-to-efficiently-initialize-texture-with-zeroes). However, I'm quite puzzled that my DRAW framebuffer is only cleared when I attached it to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`:

```
    int levels = 2;
    int potW = 2; int potH = 2;
    GLuint _potTextureName;
    glGenTextures(1, &_potTextureName);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _potTextureName);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, levels, GL_RGBA32F, potW, potH);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _potTextureName, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

    GLuint clearColor[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    glClearBufferuiv(GL_COLOR, 0, clearColor);
```

Modifying the snippet to use `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`, retaining everything else, will NOT clear the framebuffer:

```
    int levels = 2;
    int potW = 2; int potH = 2;
    GLuint _potTextureName;
    glGenTextures(1, &_potTextureName);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _potTextureName);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, levels, GL_RGBA32F, potW, potH);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _potTextureName, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);

    GLuint clearColor[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    glClearBufferuiv(GL_COLOR, 0, clearColor);
```

I tried using `glDrawBuffers` instead as suggested [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/archive/index.php/t-181057.html), and I also tried using `glClearColor` and `glClear`, but they all behave the same way. What am I missing here?

Comment: The second snippet uses a potentially different value for the format parameter of `glTexStorage2D()`. What OpenGL version are you using?

Comment: One thing I could imagine triggering such a behavior could be that you still have some other texture/renderbuffer bound at color attachment 0, which is incomatible to the new image (like a mismatch in sample counts, or layers). You should check the framebuffer completeness state. You should also check for GL errors.

Comment: @derhass , thank you for pointing out the completeness issue. It turns out to be related, and I just posted my finding as an answer.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, thanks. I edited my question to make it more clear. I'm using 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it has todo with what I previously bind to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`.

In the second case, `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` was already bound to a texture of *smaller size*. There is a note related to [Framebuffer Completeness Rules](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Completeness_Rules) that although there is no restriction on the texture size, the effective size of the FBO is the *intersection* of the sizes of all bound images. Therefore, in my second case, if the texture (1) bound to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` is bigger than what I bound to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, then the texture (1) will only be cleared partially, no matter what clear operation I used (`glClear` or `glClearBuffer*`).

The first case turns out to work for me since I only have one texture bound to the FBO, in `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`.