# glReadPixels() couldn't obain the A's value which outputng from fragement shader.

Tags: c, opengl

sush as
in fragement shader

```
FragColor = vec4(TexCoords, MicrifiedCurrentPixelLevel, 0.5); notes：A'value is 0.5.
```

I wanted to obain FragColor's value including R,G,B,A in CPU memory. however,
I used

```
float* Pixel = new float[4 * SCR_WIDTH * SCR_HEIGHT];
glReadPixels(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &Pixel[0]);
```

A'value I obained is always 1，is't 0.5.
why?
thanks very mush.

Comment: Does the renderbuffer you are rendering into have an alpha channel? What are your blending settings?

Answer (score 0):

You cant store alpha values.Check your rgba format of your empty texture.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7196109/9806560